# Bottom navigation view disappears on pixel 4

Tags: java, android, kotlin, user-interface, bottomnavigationview

I am getting this issue when only using Pixel 4 devices. I have a bottomnavigationview on my home screen and it just disappears.

Here is the code for my home screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_home_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/home_nav_graph" />
    <!--<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_fragment_container_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation" />-->

   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@color/colorWhite"
       app:itemBackground="@color/white_transparent"
       app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color"
       app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
       app:itemIconSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
       android:isScrollContainer="false"
       app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
       app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:fabCustomSize="@dimen/_35sdp"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tint="@null"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_scan_nav"
        app:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:translationZ="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:outlineProvider="none"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/bottom_navigation"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan Receipt"
        style="@style/SfProDisplay10Pt"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        app:elevation="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:translationZ="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scan_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/scan_button"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/scan_button"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:elevation="@dimen/_20sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/spendleeid_layout"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see there is a FragmentContainerView, which shows fine but on the Pixel 4, the bottomnavigationview disappears. From checking the layout inspector while debugging it seems that the bottomnavigation becomes invisible or hidden behind the view. On other devices I see it works fine. One thing that I see that fixes this issue is changing the style of the activity to include this

`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>`

I would just like to know if there is any way I can show the bottomnavigationview without using the fullscreen style. Or is there any plausible explanation for this? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try another layout like LinearLayout
it maybe help